# Suppress header on first page of section

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, header-footer

I created a header using KOMA-Script. How can I suppress this header on the first page of a section?

Comment: Am I beginning to get the impression that, despite its humungous manual, `memoir` is a "simpler" option than KOMA-Script?

Comment: Why is having an incredibly well-organized and indexed manual seen as a bad thing?  The Memoir manual is one of the best pieces of documentation I have ever had the honor of using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using a document class with chapters (which by default suppress the header on the first chapter page) and nevertheless want additional headers suppressed: Put `\thispagestyle{plain}` (or `scrplain` in case of the `scrpage2` package) immediately after any `\section` command.

If you're using a class without chapters: Consider switching to chapters.

P.S.: A minimal example would, among other things, reveal the document class.

Comment: I was trapped in the wrong document class. Thanks!